# Выбор значения с максимальной датой

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Имеется таблица с данными следующего характера

```
значение1   21.01.2012
значение1   21.02.2012
значение1   21.03.2012
значение2   21.05.2013
значение2   21.06.2015
```

и т.д.
Необходимо написать селект, который вернул бы каждое из значений в единичном экземпляре с максимальной соответствующей датой.
Иначе говоря

```
значение1   21.03.2012
значение2   21.06.2015
```

и т.д. Не знаю, как правильно в таком случае связать max и distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь ["агрегирующей функцией - max()"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) + ["group by"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2066419):

```
select value, max(date_col) 
from table_name 
group by value;
```

Comment: Да, оно. Спасибо!